# Binding a list of images to a ListBox

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, data-binding

Im trying to bind a list of images to a Listbox, but all I get is a list of Type names

```
<ListBox x:Name="PhotosListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding MyImages}" />
```

The MyImages is a `List<BitMapImages>`

Right now It just returns a list of `System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage` instead of showing the Images

EDIT
For further ref, here is the final code.

```
<ListBox x:Name="PhotosListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding MyImages}" >
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Image Source="{Binding}" Stretch="Uniform"></Image>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, the `ToString()` method of the bound data type will be invoked, which by default will return the fully qualified type name.

You should define a custom [ItemTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521.aspx) for the ListBox.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use an `ItemTemplate` other than the default so that the `ListBox` knows how to handle the data type being passed to it.

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521.aspx

Comment: Accepted devdigital's answer, simply because it was 1 min. faster, but thanks for your help.