# How to bind image in metro style app to binary image?

Tags: visual-studio, xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I create a GridView App and i want to bind the images in the GridView to values that i get it from web service,i received the images as strings(binary)

i use C# programing language and Sql Server data base

Comment: The question is too vague in its current form. Please say what you tried or ask about more specific problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get a list from the web service, convert it to a list of BitmapImage objects that specify UriSource based on the source list and bind that list to GridView.ItemsSource. Then set GridView.ItemTemplate/DataTemplate to an Image that binds its Source to the BitmapImage in the collection.

You probably want your web service to talk to SQL Server - I suppose you can use ADO.NET, Entity Framework or other such things.

Comment: thank you for your replay, i convert it to list of BitmapImage objects ,unfortunately i didn't understand the rest of your solution can you explain more or give an example like this,and thank you again

Comment: Your question is too broad, so the answer is just as broad - I am just trying to point you at the keywords you could use to bing for the answers. Searching for ItemsSource, ItemTemplate, Image yields this earlier question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6650922/binding-a-list-of-images-to-a-listbox (ListBoxes and GridViews share a common API here since they both derive from ItemsControl).